# Installing Arch Linux on caching SSD

Tags: arch-linux, ssd

I installed Arch on a VM and I liked it, so I would like to install it on my laptop.
My laptop is a Asus Zenbook s55l, which has a 24G SSD that was previously used for intel SRT.
I would like to install Arch on this SSD.

Will the little space available give me trouble ? Should I mount specific directories to the HDD for more space ?

Answer (score 1):

Arch Linux is very flexible.  You can do minimal installs, huge graphics stacks, and everything in between.  24GB is plenty even for a simple desktop system.

Comment: And should I mount /home on my HDD for more personal space ? What about programs ?